# Website hangs - PHP app on server with intermittent hang

Tags: php, apache

I have a website which hangs about 20 times a day for between one and ten minutes. I have a hosting company who cannot find the problem, I have an application developer who cannot find the problem and they both blame each other. Its the Server, says the developer as is doesnt show on the Dev Server. Its the Application, says the Host, as they can't find any error log issues.

Can anyone offer me a few hours consultancy to get to the cause of the problem?

Comment: this is NOT rent a coder

Comment: No, its a place you ask for help and expertise...

Comment: @UVuuMe, I think you've missed the point. This site allows you to post a question, to which people can answer. Your asking people to find the question for you, then answer it...

Comment: Understood. Just trying to figure out what question to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is - while the server is hanging - check an other page/file on your website/webapplication server. If that opens fine, logic dictates that its not your hosting company. Also check on other computers/internet pages then your own. It could be a local problem. I think you must log all tasks; see what is eating up your connection and/or cpu during the 10 minutes.

Comment: Also confirm that it's happening when the site is accessed from more than one computer. I once had a site that I thought was going down for long periods while I was working on it, but it turned out that Chrome was just refusing to access it after it returned a certain number of 500 errors.

Comment: OK. In answer, all the pages generated by the application hang at the same time. Repeated tries seams not to unhang them, but then it releases. No indication of why and when. As far as Internet connectivity, all other sites fine. We've looked at cookies, compressed them, and then tested on the dev server, and thats not the cause.

Comment: Also, I use a Website Monitor and it now flags when pages don't respond, so its logged. There is no problem with ping when the pages hang, as a separate ping monitor shows green.

Comment: My suspicion is different versions of services on Apache, but its hard to know which services to aks the Hosting Techs to look at.

Comment: Simply ask them to log all tasks and services for like a day every minute, then when it happens again, write down the time, look at the log at that time and voila you know what it is causing hopefully :) If not, maybe a fresh install will help or as stated go to freelance.com orso and hire some second opinion. Good luck